# How do I make a score counter in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code:

```
def quiz():

    print("Here is a quiz to test your knowledge!")
    print()
    print("Question 1")
    print("How tall is the Eiffel Tower?")
    print("a. 350m")
    print("b. 342m")
    print("c. 324m")
    print("d. 1000ft")
    answer = input("Make your choice : ")
    if answer == "c" :
        print ("Correct!")
    if answer == "a" :
        print ("Wrong!")
    if answer == "b" :
        print ("Wrong!")
    if answer == "d" :
        print ("Wrong!")
    print()
    print("Question 2")
    print("How loud is a sonic boom?")
    print("a. 160dB")
    print("b. 175dB")
    print("c. 157dB")
    print("d. 213dB")
    answer = input("Make your choice : ")
    if answer == "d" :
        print ("Correct!")

    if answer == "a" :
        print ("Wrong!")
    if answer == "b" :
        print ("Wrong!")
    if answer == "c" :
        print ("Wrong!")
    print()
    print("Question 3")
    print("How hot is Pluto?")
    print("a. 223⁰C to -233⁰C")
    print("b. -323⁰C to -347⁰C")
    print("c. -375⁰F to -395⁰F")
    print("d. -213⁰C to -237⁰C")
    answer = input("Make your choice : ")
    if answer == "c" :
        print ("Correct!")
        score + 1
    if answer == "a" :
        print ("Wrong!")
    if answer == "b" :
        print ("Wrong!")
    if answer == "d" :
        print ("Wrong!")
    print()
    print("Question 4")
    print("How many calories in a normal Twix bar?")
    print("a. 284")
    print("b. 297")
    print("c. 314")
    print("d. 329")
    answer = input("Make your choice : ")
    if answer == "a" :
        print ("Correct!")
        score + 1
    if answer == "c" :
        print ("Wrong!")
    if answer == "b" :
        print ("Wrong!")
    if answer == "d" :
        print ("Wrong!")
    print()
    print("Question 5")
    print("How deep is Mariana Trench?")
    print("a. 12.9km")
    print("b. 11.7km")
    print("c. 12.4km")
    print("d. 11.0km")
    answer = input("Make your choice : ")
    if answer == "d" :
        print ("Correct!")
        score + 1
    if answer == "a" :
        print ("Wrong!")
    if answer == "b" :
        print ("Wrong!")
    if answer == "c" :
        print ("Wrong!")
    print()
    print("Question 6")
    print("How many states are there in the USA?")
    print("a. 50")
    print("b. 59")
    print("c. 65")
    print("d. 48")
    answer = input("Make your choice : ")
    if answer == "a" :
        print ("Correct!")
        score + 1
    if answer == "c" :
        print ("Wrong!")
    if answer == "b" :
        print ("Wrong!")
    if answer == "d" :
        print ("Wrong!")
    print()
    print("Question 7")
    print("How many balls on a snooker table?")
    print("a. 25")
    print("b. 22")
    print("c. 21")
    print("d. 19")
    answer = input("Make your choice : ")
    if answer == "b" :
        print ("Correct!")
        score + 1
    if answer == "a" :
        print ("Wrong!")
    if answer == "c" :
        print ("Wrong!")
    if answer == "d" :
        print ("Wrong!")
    print(score)
```

I would like to insert a score counter which would add a point every time the user gets one right and does nothing when they get one wrong. I would like it to be very simple and easy to write (I am new to Python).

How would I do this?

Comment: Consider using a 'else' instead of multiple `ifs ... wrong`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not part of the question, but conside using a dictionary or list to store the questions, options and answer and just loop over:

```
questions = {
    "How tall is the Eiffel Tower?":['a. 350m', 'b. 342m', 'c. 324m', 'd. 1000ft','a'],
    "How loud is a sonic boom?":['a. 160dB', 'b. 175dB', 'c. 157dB', 'd. 213dB', 'd']
} # 1

score = 0 # 2 
for question_number,question in enumerate(questions): # 3
    print ("Question",question_number+1) # 4
    print (question)
    for options in questions[question][:-1]: # 5
        print (options)
    user_choice = input("Make your choice : ")
    if user_choice == questions[question][-1]: # 6
        print ("Correct!")
        score += 1 #7 here's the relevant part of the question
    else: # 8
        print ("Wrong!")

print(score) #9
```

Explanation:

1. `question` is a [python dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), it has a `key` and a `value`, the key in this case is the question, the value is a `list`, in this list we have all the possible options, and in the last item the answer;
2. Here's the `score`, note that it is outside the `for loop`, because we wan't to maintain it over all the question, just increment it if correct.
3. in order to get the header "Question x", I've used a `enumerate`, it takes a `iterable` as argument, I've used the dictionary question, it will iterate over it's keys(the questions in it), and returns two variables, the `question_number` and the `question`.
4. enumerator starts in the index 0, so we add 1 to it to display the first question as "Question 1" instead of "Question 0"
5. we loop over the values of the question, the syntax is dictionary[key], the options, since we don't want to show the answer we use [-1] to remove the last item
6. now we check if the answer is correct, if the user_choice is equal to the last item in the values of the dicionary(remember the [-1] refers to the last item).
7. if the answer is correct we increment the score by 1
8. else we just print "wrong"
9. after all the questions are displayed we print the score.

Comment: Imho a better data structure is a list of tuples, '[(q1,(a11,a12,a13,a14),ans1), ...]` so that the program can present the questions in a given order, and also to reflect the immutability of the questionnaire. That said a good answer, with stress on the usefulness of abstraction.

Comment: Indeed, tuples are good, but they lack one small detail, they get quite weird in accessing them, and to show a newcomer a nested list of tuples, with multiple levels of depths, is quite overburden. Dictionaries are more friendly to new users.

Comment: And to avoid unordered question one can still use a OrderedDict

Comment: how would you do this with a global score? as global score will give, TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Answer (score 0):

You are part way there with:

```
if answer == "a" :
    print ("Correct!")
    score + 1
```

However, you need to assign the new value to `score`:

```
if answer == "a" :
    print ("Correct!")
    score = score + 1
```

And you need to start your function with:

```
score = 0
```

Comment: I would also argue for a data driven structure by putting all the question-option-answer tuples in a list and looping over that. But the question didn't ask for that.

Comment: how would you do this with a global score? as  global score will give, TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str